# How to refresh Octave's knowledge of class methods?

Tags: octave

I have defined an [MCV example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) class in Octave called `myobj`. Its constructor is located in the relative path `@myobj/myobj.m`:

```
function c = myobj(arg = "hi")
   s.arg = arg;
   c = class(s, "myobj");
end
```

When I run `octave-cli` and construct an instance of this class, Octave doesn't know how to describe/print it:

```
octave:1> o = myobj()
o = <class myobj>
```

I am aware of using the `display` class method to allow this. Now I have added the file `@myobj/display.m` with the contents:

```
function display(obj)
   printf("%s = <arg = \"%s\">\n", inputname(1), obj.arg);
end
```

But Octave does not find this new class function. After doing some research, some said that running the command `rehash` or `clear all` would cause Octave to find the new function, but they don't:

```
octave:2> o = myobj()
o = <class myobj>
octave:3> rehash
octave:4> o = myobj()
o = <class myobj>
octave:5> clear all
octave:6> o = myobj()
o = <class myobj>
octave:7> clear -a
octave:8> o = myobj()
o = <class myobj>
octave:9> clear -a *
octave:10> o = myobj()
o = <class myobj>
octave:11> clear -c *
octave:12> o = myobj()
o = <class myobj>
```

Restarting Octave does solve this:

```
octave:1> o = myobj()
o = <arg = "hi">
```

The problem occurs again when this function is removed without restarting Octave:

```
octave:2> o = myobj()
error: no such file, '/tmp/tmp.6ms6lw2GW0/@myobj/display.m'
octave:2> rehash
octave:3> o = myobj()
error: no such file, '/tmp/tmp.6ms6lw2GW0/@myobj/display.m'
octave:3> clear all
octave:4> o = myobj()
error: no such file, '/tmp/tmp.6ms6lw2GW0/@myobj/display.m'
octave:4> clear all *
octave:5> o = myobj()
error: no such file, '/tmp/tmp.6ms6lw2GW0/@myobj/display.m'
octave:5> clear -a
octave:6> o = myobj()
error: no such file, '/tmp/tmp.6ms6lw2GW0/@myobj/display.m'
octave:6> clear -a *
octave:7> o = myobj()
error: no such file, '/tmp/tmp.6ms6lw2GW0/@myobj/display.m'
octave:7> clear -c *
octave:8> o = myobj()
error: no such file, '/tmp/tmp.6ms6lw2GW0/@myobj/display.m'
octave:9> clear display
octave:10> o = myobj()
error: no such file, '/tmp/tmp.6ms6lw2GW0/@myobj/display.m'
```

Does anyone know of a command that I can run to cause Octave to become aware of these function changes? This isn't too bad with the CLI of course, but I do like to use the GUI, and restarting it can be tiresome.

Note: I am using v4.2.1, configured for "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".

EDIT: I am able to reproduce this on Windows 10 with v4.2.2, configured for "x86_64-w64-mingw32".

Comment: I'm using GNU Octave 4.2.1 on Debian and creating the file `display.m` is sufficient, no need for `rehash` or `clear all`. Do you have anything special? Filesystem without proper file timestamp, no atime, no ctime (Something which would prevent Octave from noticing, that the file was modified)

Comment: @Andy Thanks for replying. This is occurring for me on Fedora 25 on /tmp and in my ext4 home directory, and on Windows 10 on an NTFS partition. If there is something different it must be very subtle. I haven't compiled the source myself, just installed it from either DNF on Fedora 25 or downloaded from the official site for Windows. This is very confusing!

Comment: Hm, man you try to move `display.m` out of the @myobj directory and put it back, does this trigger the "reload"?

Comment: Hi Doddy, this is a known, but alas difficult bug to track as it does not occur in all setups (as @Andy confirmed). Relevant bugs (submitted by me) [here](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?46281) and [here](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?46282). Octave normally has a "rescanning" process to update function definitions when folder contents change; as Mike suggests there, it may have something to do with how directories are not always rescanned under very specific conditions, hence causing this bug. Personally I have gotten used to restarting the GUI every time I update a class.

Comment: You might also want to play with `ignore_function_time_stamp` (e.g. setting it to `none`; see [here](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Miscellaneous-Techniques.html) and [here](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Function-Files.html#index-ignore_005ffunction_005ftime_005fstamp)) but I don't remember it working for me at the time the bugs were submitted. Maybe things have changed in the latest version of octave. You might even want to try manually readding your class directory (not the functions themselves) into the path, on the chance this causes a 'rescan'.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can confirm your bug on my system too (standard octave 4.2.1 installation from source, Linux Mint 64bit), and that none of the above suggestions work other than restarting the GUI. I do heavily suspect that people unable to confirm this bug simply do not follow the same steps in the same order as they're used to a different workflow (e.g. write the files first, open octave to test second, which would clearly hide the buggy behaviour).

Comment: Also worth pointing out (as per the submitted bugs) this is not exclusive to classes. It also happens when creating new private functions, functions inside namespaces, or altering system functions. Perhaps there's simply a bug in `ignore_function_time_stamp` that has gone undetected, and functionality depending on it is broken.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou since it's almost 2,5years since you've reported the bugs, have you done any bugtracking since then?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Thanks for your feedback, glad it's not just me! I might take a look at this, as I was hoping to learn more of the Octave internals for a future project of mine.

Comment: @Andy you mean if I checked to see if someone else reported it? No, I got so used to simply restarting octave that I forgot about it myself. I'm assuming the bugs haven't generated much interest on account of people being unable to reproduce them faithfully (even though I'm secretly betting they're reproducible if the steps are followed correctly, since I've been able to reproduce them on every single machine I've ever tried).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou No, I thought compiling Octave with symbols, attaching gdb, trying to find the place where tracking of file changes and indexing new files happens.

Comment: @Andy hahah, oh, you mean debugging. No I haven't. I could try for fun, but debugging octave source wasn't a priority even back when I was using it for work (which I'm not anymore) ... I doubt I'll find the time now. Plus, I'm not familiar with octave's internals, I wouldn't even know where to start. I'd waste more time trying to figure out what's going on than chasing actual bugs. I suppose `ignore_function_time_stamp` would be a good place to start looking from though, if I ever did feel adventurous ... :)

Answer (score 1):

I landed on this question when searching for an answer to the same problem. In reality, the latest versions of Octave have [this bug](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?55887) fixed already.

The easiest way to activate your edits to the class methods is to use the command `clear functions` and then create a new object of that class. Any old objects of that class will continue using the old methods.

Comment: This clears class methods from memory, they’ll have to be reloaded from disk if you use them after. To clear the class definition itself (eg if you add or remove a variable) use `clear classes`.

Comment: It's been a little while since I looked at this but I submitted a fix myself. It shouldn't be necessary to run any `clear`-related commands at all. https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?54636