# How do I make Octave suggest the methods of my class when I hit tab and show their help text?

Tags: octave

I want to write a new class in Octave but I found that although Octave do find the new files, it does not suggests neither its methods nor its constructor when I am typing in the console. Also, I want to document this class, but `help` does not always find the files, thus being unable to extract the help text.

For purpose of demonstration, I created two classes `baz` ([using the newer classdef](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.2/classdef-Classes.html)) and `foo` ([using the older class definition](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.2/Creating-a-Class.html)). This is the resulting tree of files:

```
.
├───@baz
│       baz.m
│
└───@foo
        display.m
        foo.m
        getValFoo.m
```

And these are their contents (comments #1 through #5 are placeholders):

```
% ------------- ./@baz/baz.m ----------------
%% [#1]

classdef baz
%% [#2]
  properties
    val = 0;
  endproperties
  
  methods
  %% [#3]
    function b = baz ()
    %% [#4]
      b.val = 7;
    endfunction
    
    function v = getValBaz (b)
    %% [#5]
      v = b.val;
    endfunction
    
    function display (b)
      printf ('baz of value %i\n', getValBaz (b));
    endfunction
  endmethods
endclassdef

% ------------- ./@foo/foo.m ----------------
%% Creates a 'foo' with value of 3.

function f = foo ()
  f.val = 3;
  f = class (f, 'foo');
endfunction

% ----------- ./@foo/display.m -------------- 
function display (f)
  printf ('foo of value %i\n', getValFoo (f));
endfunction

% ---------- ./@foo/getValFoo.m -------------
%% Returns de value of a 'foo'.

function v = getValFoo (f)
  v = f.val;
endfunction
```

After preparing the classes, I open Octave and check if all files are there:

```
>> dir
.      ..     @baz         @foo
>> dir @baz
.      ..     baz.m
>> dir @foo
.      ..     display.m    foo.m      getValFoo.m
```

Now test the constructors:

```
>> baz(), foo()
baz of value 7
foo of value 3
```

And try `help`:

```
>> help baz
error: help: 'baz' is not documented
>> help foo
'foo' is a function from the file [PATH REDACTED]\@foo\foo.m

 Creates a 'foo' with value of 3.
```

In `@baz/baz.m` I tried putting the help in different positions (see comments #1 through #4), but neither worked.

Now I use TAB key to see a list of suggestions, hoping to find `getValBaz` and `getValFoo`:

```
>> get
get                      geteuid                  getpid
get_first_help_sentence  getfield                 getppid
get_help_text            getgid                   getpref
get_help_text_from_file  getgrent                 getpwent
get_home_directory       getgrgid                 getpwnam
getappdata               getgrnam                 getpwuid
getegid                  gethostname              getrusage
getenv                   getpgrp                  getuid
```

I can't find their help either, but they both work:

```
>> help getValBaz
error: help: 'getValBaz' not found
>> getValBaz(baz())
ans =  7
>> help getValFoo
error: help: 'getValFoo' not found
>> getValFoo(foo())
ans =  3
```

Now I try adding the `@` folders to the search path:

```
>> addpath('@baz')
>> help getValBaz
error: help: 'getValBaz' not found
>> addpath('@foo')
warning: function @foo\display.m shadows
>> help getValFoo
'getValFoo' is a function from the file [PATH REDACTED]\@foo\getValFoo.m

 Returns de value of a 'foo'.
```

It finally works for `foo` -- which doesn't use `classdef` -- but I receive a warning that the overloading `@foo/display.m`  overshadows native `display`. And since `help` won't even find `getValBaz`, putting a help text in position #5 in `@baz/baz.m` does not work.

Finally, these are my questions:

1. How can I make Octave suggest the methods when I hit TAB?
2. How do I make `help` find the files and extract help text without having to resort to the older style of class definition and not having to add the `@` folder to the search path?
3. Where is the proper position for documenting a class constructor in a `classdef` file? And what about documentation for its methods?

I am running Octave version 4.2.1 configured for "x86_64-w64-mingw32" on Windows 7. Because of [Octave's not refreshing classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49335462/), I am mainly using the CLI to write my class, but I found the same behavior using the GUI. I also tried packaging these classes and installing it with `pkg install`, but this behavior persisted.

*Addendum:* My final goal is to produce a package. Therefore, since I can use the older style of class definition and avoid the problem in question 3, questions 1 and 2 -- which are a common behaviors after you load a pre-installed package, such as `control` or `signal` -- are more important to me.

Comment: this is not just a problem with custom classes. octave struggles a bit with class documentation (particularly classdef). however, at least with the old style, this isn't too much of a problem, because all methods are accumulated in a bespoke folder and can be searched separately.  Consider, e.g. the `function_handle` function from the symbolic package, of the `@sym` class. To bring its documentation you need to do `help @sym/function_handle`.  `help function_handle` will not work. But finding out what methods are defined in the `@sym` class is as easy as `ls @sym` (from the shell)

Comment: btw, in theory, octave supports the `Contents.m` file, like matlab does, and this would also work for `@` and `+` style folders ... but for some reason I can't get it to work now ... perhaps a regression bug? I'll submit a report on the bug tracker. Having said that, many packages still employ a `Contents.m` file, even as a convention. So you could do this too (i.e. put a `Contents.m` file in your old-style classfolder)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Since I want to produce a package, besides help texts, having Octave suggest the methods when someone hits TAB, as it happens with other pre-installed packages, is important to me. However, I think what I can do now is to add `INDEX` to the package and not use `classdef` files. This way users could use `pkg describe pkg_name -verbose' and then `help`. Do you have a better suggestion, perhaps?

Comment: I think the way this happens for most packages is that they rely on adding things to the path upon loading. You will notice that packages that only add a class folder on the path, do not readily show class methods. E.g. look at the symbolic package, as I said above. My suggestion would be either add things to the path to make them visible, or keep the class functionality as you do now, and raise the issue with the devs. They are usually very good at addressing these issues; perhaps there simply wasn't enough demand so far. Alternatively, even better, if you can do it, then do and help octave!